# How getSet of Tuples from row in cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra

I have a table with set < frozen < tuple < text, text > > > column.
I can't understand how I may read a column value from a row.

I can create TupleType with

```
val tupleType = cluster.getMetadata.newTupleType(DataType.text, DataType.text)
```

I try read column value, but I can not understand which class I must pass to

```
row.getSet("column_with_set", ??? ).asScala
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was on the surface.

[About using tuples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/manual/tuples/)

About needed type.

```
row
  .getSet("column_with_set", classOf[TupleValue])
  .asScala
  .map(p => (p.getString(0), p.getString(1)))
```